# I want to add a 5TB HD (NTFS) to my time capsule and have access to it from both my Mac and my PC's

Tags: hard-drive, airport, time-capsule, ntfs

I want to add a 5TB HD (NTFS) to my time capsule. I have both Mac and PC's and will like to access the drive from both. I can see that the drive is attached in airport utility on my windows pc but I can't access it(probably because of the NTFS partition). I am not seeing anything at all in airport utility on my Mac (probably because it's not in HFS+ format).
I think I can partition the drive into two drives, one NTFS and the other HFS+ but I will only do that if it's my only choice. I would rather have access to everything from both Mac and PC............

HELP!!!

Comment: How do you wanna access your additional 5 TB drive attached to the time capsule? Constantly over the network or by attaching it to the Macs/PCs from time to time?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to Apple's instructions on how to mount the drives on both sides if they don't seem to show up. [How to mount a Time Capsule HD](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT1331)

The only disk formats that the Time Capsules support are HFS (Macs default), FAT16, and FAT32. [Supported HD for Time Capsule](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202807). Since you have a large HD you cannot use FAT16 as it is made for smaller HD's (<2GB).

If you would like to use Apple's Default (HFS) you will have to install software on the PC in order to write to the drive. Paragon-software has the tools needed to use HFS on windows computers

If you use FAT32 both your windows and Mac will be able to read/write from the HD.